# Unable to start tomcat with jdk 1.5 64bit

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

I have following configuration and installation in my System:

```
 -Java 5 64bit (jdk-1_5_0_16-windows-amd64)
 -Tomcat 5.5.27
 -Windows7 64bit
```

[image]

When i start Tomcat i found following error in log.

```
[2015-03-10 16:39:01] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2015-03-10 16:39:01] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2015-03-10 16:39:01] [info] Run service finished.
[2015-03-10 16:39:01] [info] Procrun finished.
```

I search through but unable to solve problem.

Comment: which jdk did you use before ?

Comment: same JDK version but 32bit

Comment: maybe you could check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-error-prunsrvc-failed-creating-java-jvmdll/) link

Comment: Unable to work for me, have already checked.

Comment: The windows version of tomcat 5.5 is 32bit VM compatible only - the binaries for running it are **not** 64bit binaries, which would be required to run it with a 64bit VM (This was tested with the installer from http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.27/bin/, which installed into `C:\Program Files (x86)\`, which indicates a 32bit install).

Comment: so,what should i do to solve problem.

Comment: i have test with same configuration in eclipse and it run perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_23800126.html) ?

Comment: eclipse is a completely different beast to tomcat. It's like comparing apples and oranges. There is a 32 & 64 bit installer for eclipse; if you're using a 64bit VM, you use the 64bit installer. If there's no 64bit installer, you have to use, and reference, a 32bit VM. Alternatively try with tomcat 6, which supports 32bit & 64bit installations.

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, i have no choice for tomcat 6.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to just install and use a 32bit VM for tomcat then. It's frustrating, but it's your only choice if you can't upgrade (I presume it's because you're hanging off some JSP 2.0 behaviour)

Comment: i want to use 64bit jvm because of memory issue in 32bit jvm(Out of memory)

Comment: Check out [Install Tomcat 5.5 using windows installer which works for 64 bit as well - Installer attached](http://www.seemoredata.com/en/showthread.php?85-Installing-Tomcat-and-Java-on-64-bit-windows-machine) or [Tomcat 5.5.27 Windows Installer](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/tomcat/5.5.27#package_detail_tabs).

Comment: If there's an x64 directory below bin on the tomcat (I unzipped the original .zip file rather than relying on the installer), then you should try moving those to bin, and retry your setup efforts - my original determination of the lack of 64bit support was erroneous. If you had installed tomcat previously it may have picked up the 32bit VM on the original install and this is blocking execution efforts

Answer (score 0):

**This is usually happen because of missing `msvcr71.dll` file.** However *tomcat doesn’t use msvcr71.dll directly*, it’s used by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

**Solution**

1. Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to tomcat’s bin folder.
2. Add java’s bin directory to windows environment variable.
3. Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to windows\system32 folder.
4. Make sure your tomcat’s pointing to correct jvm.dll folder.

Originally posted by @mkyong [Tomcat Error – Prunsrv.C Failed Creating Java (Jvm.Dll)](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-error-prunsrvc-failed-creating-java-jvmdll/)

Comment: Unable to find msvcr71.dll in bin directory

Comment: I have uploaded this file on free file hosting server. You can download it from [MSVCR71.zip - Download link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=18046493781925467742)

Comment: Still unable to start

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/095gkgnadk/trouble-starting-tomcat-error-0-on-windows-64bit) post. Here is lot of discussion on starting Tomcat on 64 bit JVM.

Comment: Ya, i go through it but unable to find desire solution.